# TypeError: initial_value must be str or none, not bytes in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

Here is my code:

```
import imaplib
from email.parser import HeaderParser
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
conn.login('example@gmail.com', 'password')
conn.select()
conn.search(None, 'ALL')
data = conn.fetch('1', '(BODY[HEADER])')
header_data = data[1][0][1]
parser = HeaderParser()
msg = parser.parsestr(header_data)
```

From this i get the error message:

```
TypeError: initial_value must be str or none, not bytes
```

Im using python 3 which apparently automatically decodes. So why am i still getting this error message?

Comment: What line do you receive that error on?

Comment: msg = parser.parsestr(header_data)

Answer (score 16):

You can try:

```
header_data = data[1][0][1].decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This works, thanks. With Python 2 you are not required to use the decode()

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest do this,(Python 3)

```
typ, data = conn.fetch('1', '(RFC822)') # will read the first email
email_content = data[0][1] 
msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_content) # this needs to be corrected in your case 
emailDate =  msg["Date"]
emaiSubject = msg["Subject"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a [BytesHeaderParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.parser.BytesParser) in this case.